# Ignore property when wrong type due deserialization in json.net

Tags: c#, json, json.net

In my c# app I use `json.net` library for working with jsons.

 I have situation:

Property:

```
[JsonProperty("my_test_property_json_key", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
public int[] MyTestProperty{ get; set; }
```

When my json for this proprty looks like:

```
[0,1,2,3,4,5]
```

All works great.
But possible situation when I have wrong json value like:

```
[[0,1,2,3]]
```

And in this situation I get Exception:

```
[Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException] = {"Error reading integer. Unexpected token: StartArray. Path 'my_test_property_json_key[0]', line 1, position 3250."}
```

Correct behavior in this situation should be:

return empty `int[]`.

How I can ignore this property, when I have wrong json (property exist, but it is a different type)?

Note: My json is too big (a lot of other properties)- and I can't to recreate it with default data (I can not lose data).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom converter that tries to read an array of integers, and returns an empty array if the data isn't correct:

```
class MyCustomInt32ArrayConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override object ReadJson(
        JsonReader reader,
        Type objectType,
        Object existingValue,
        JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var array = serializer.Deserialize(reader) as JArray;
        if (array != null)
        {
            return array.Where(token => token.Type == JTokenType.Integer)
                        .Select(token => token.Value<int>())
                        .ToArray();
        }
        return new int[0];
    }

    public override void WriteJson(
        JsonWriter writer,
        Object value,
        JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, value);
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(int[]);
    }
}
```

Just apply the converter to the property using the `JsonConverterAttribute` attribute :

```
[JsonConverterAttribute(typeof(MyCustomInt32ArrayConverter))]
[JsonProperty("my_test_property_json_key", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
public int[] MyTestProperty{ get; set; }
```

Comment: Why in 'WriteJson' you throw exception? Also no validation in 'Can convert'((

Comment: @jimpanzer, it's just a basic example, and I didn't bother to implement it completely. You only need to implement WriteJson and CanConvert if you want to serialize as well as deserialize.

Comment: thank. Now it looks better. (previous comment I wrote, because someone can use such code without modifications. But now I think it should work in any situation). But usage of converter - this is not the best ability. Maybe somehow I can just set some json attribute to property?

Comment: "usage of converter - this is not the best ability": what makes you say that? If you know a better approach, why are you asking the question in the first place? ;)

Comment: I do not know a better solution, I'm just guessing that "there must be better";) I was hoping for any attribute, assigning which: parsing  error - use the default value.